# VBA - copy sheet from Application.GetOpenFilename()

Tags: vba

I would like to browse to the specific excel file and copy sheet1 of the file which is opening into the new sheet in my xlsm file. I have written the code like below:

```
Option Explicit
Sub test_copy_sheet()
    Dim path As String
    Dim filetoopen As Variant
    Dim openwb As Workbook
    filetoopen = Application.GetOpenFilename()
    If filetoopen <> False Then
        Set openwb = Application.Workbooks.Open(filetoopen)
            openwb.Sheets(1).Copy
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add.Name = "mysheet"
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("mysheet").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        openwb.Close False
    End If
End Sub
```

When i ran the code, it get the issue as photo
[image]
I just want to copy sheet1 of the file opening to sheet name "mysheet". Could you please assist on this ?

Comment: I think you're copying the sheet1 object, not it's contents, so pastespecial won't work.  I cant see the error images at work, can you detail the error also.

Comment: `thiworkbook` That's a typo which you meant to be `ThisWorkBook`.. Please insert `Option Explicit` at the top of the module to help you identify variables that are not declared properly (which will also help you pick up typo like this!).

Comment: [Don't post pictures of exeptions](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/), copy the error instead. I think `OpenBook.Close False` causes the error, as `OpenBook` does not exist. I recommend setting `Option Explicit` everywhere (see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-explicit-statement)).

Comment: i have modify this post , it seems that it can not paste the entire sheet1 from the sheet opening into my expected sheet. So which option i can try instead ".PasteSpecial xlPasteValues"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, please insert `Option Explicit` at the top of the module to ensure you declare all variables properly (and also pick up typo like `thisworkbook` and `OpenBook`)

Try this code below, it will open the file, copy the first sheet to `ThisWorkbook` and rename to `mysheet`:

```
Sub test_copy_sheet()
    Dim filetoopen As Variant
    Dim openwb As Workbook
             
    filetoopen = Application.GetOpenFilename()
    If filetoopen <> False Then
        Set openwb = Application.Workbooks.Open(filetoopen, ReadOnly:=True)
            openwb.Sheets(1).Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
            
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name = "mysheet"
            openwb.Close
    End If
End Sub
```

Note: You will need to add additional check to be sure that `ThisWorkbook` does not have a sheet named `mysheet`. (i.e. no duplicate names)